# WriteBitcodeToFile terminates program

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

i execute this simple code, but on "WriteBitcodeToFile" happned exception :
 "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc"
I don't understand why it happens(. 
Now i use llvm 3.6.1, i use clang++ 3.6.1.
On llvm 3.3 code works fine.

callstack:

> 0 raise   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 0   0x7ffff6da10d5
>   1 abort   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 0   0x7ffff6da483b
>   2 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff76cbd4d
>   3 ??  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff76c9d96
>   4 std::terminate()    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff76c9de1
>   5 __cxa_throw /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff76c9ff8   6  operator new(unsigned
>   long) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff76ca4fc
>   7 std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long,
>   std::allocator
>   const&)   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff7709659
>   8 std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator const&, unsigned
>   long) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff770a3fb
>   9 std::basic_string, std::allocator
>
> > ::basic_string(std::string const&)   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6    0   0x7ffff770aadc
> >     10    llvm::Twine::str() const    Twine.cpp   19  0x6e43c3
> >     11    llvm::Triple::Triple(llvm::Twine const&)    Triple.cpp  449 0x6dec99
> >     12    llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(llvm::Module const*,
> >     llvm::raw_ostream&)   BitcodeWriter.cpp   2071    0x42eee5
> >     13    main    main.cpp    43  0x40da26

code:

```
std::error_code err_code;
llvm::LLVMContext &ctx = llvm::getGlobalContext();
llvm::Module *mod;
llvm::SMDiagnostic Err;


std::string filename = InputFilename;

mod = llvm::parseIRFile(filename,Err,ctx).get();

llvm::StringRef sRefName(OutputFilename);
llvm::raw_fd_ostream raw(sRefName, err_code,  (llvm::sys::fs::OpenFlags)8);
 llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(mod, raw); // SIGABORT
```

Comment: std::bad_alloc seems to suggest you're running out of memory.
Also, llvm::parseIR returns a std::unique_ptr and you're using a plain Module*. Try using the correct type there.